# React Native - Expo Go to Test Flight Error

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, testflight, expo-go

I'm building a mobile app using react native. The app works perfectly in Expo Go right now.

When I run eas build and create an ios build and submit it to TestFlight I experience an issue that does not occur on the same app when I run it on Expo Go.

I have a screen with a list of items. Each item has a button that renders a modal. The modal might have no values or it might be populated with data collected from a database depending if values exist in the database. If there are no values in the db the modal doesnt load at all. If there are values that are fetched then the modal loads fine. Once the modal has failed to load once and I try to load it again the component is unresponsive.

This behaviour is odd because it works perfectly fine in expo go where if there are no values the modal will load unpopulated.

Attempts to resolve and debug this error :

1. Someone online uninstalled expo-updates and that fixed a similar issue for them but this didn't work for me.
2. Cannot reproduce the error outside of the TestFlight version.
3. Sentry is not returning any error.

Any thoughts on this would be great.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/datastore": "^4.6.1",
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^5.0.2",
    "@expo-google-fonts/bungee": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo-google-fonts/dev": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.15",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
    "@sentry/react-native": "5.5.0",
    "@shopify/flash-list": "1.4.3",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^6.2.0",
    "aws-amplify": "^5.3.1",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1418.0",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "expo": "^49.0.0",
    "expo-camera": "~13.4.2",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.6",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.4.2",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-image": "~1.3.2",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-base64": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-blob-util": "^0.18.3",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-web": "^0.19.7",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  },
```

Comment: Figured it out. Changing from java 8 to java 11, deleting node modules folder and resinstalling using npm install and then running eas build seemed to fix it.